# I'm setting up ads on my mobile app and getting an error saying that mAdView wasn't resolved

Tags: java, android, admob, ads

In Java Android Studio when I look at my code, I see the error: Cannot resolve symbol "mAdView"
I checked on the AdMob website and it seems I did the code right but I get this error.

Here is my main java code:

```
package com.example.javaamogbutton;

import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.Button;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;
import com.google.android.gms.ads.MobileAds;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Button amogussus = findViewById(R.id.amogus);
        final MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this,R.raw.amongus);

        amogussus.setOnClickListener(v -> mediaPlayer.start()); {

        }

        MobileAds.initialize(this, initializationStatus -> {
        });
        mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
    }
}
```

build.gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.example.javaamogbutton'
    compileSdk 33

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.javaamogbutton"
        minSdk 27
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:22.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
}
```

main_activity.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MyActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/amogus"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/amogussus"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:textSize="24sp"/>

    <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
        xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:id="@+id/adView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        ads:adSize="BANNER"
        ads:adUnitId="MY_ID">
    </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Importing AdView and other imports didn't work. My program said `import com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView;` was an unused import.

Answer (score 1):

You have not declared the type of mAdView. Try adding

> `AdView`

before mAdView to make the mAdView an AdView.

Comment: This worked, yet my app crashed when I ran it. EDIT: I got the app to work, but my ad failed to load in the catalog.

Comment: What is exact crash log?

Answer (score 0):

Try this line

```
 app:adSize="BANNER"
 app:adUnitId="MY_ID"
```

Full Code

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
      xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      android:id="@+id/adView"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      app:adSize="BANNER"
      app:adUnitId="MY_ID">
```